# Processing file in memory line by line and producing file like object in python

Tags: python, postgresql, file, sed, copy

I need to import a large CSV file into postgresql. The file uses two delimiters "," (comma), and "_" (underscore).

postgres `copy` command is unable to use two delimiter characters so I process the file in bash before I load it to the database:

```
cat large_file.csv \ 
| sed -e 's/_/,/' \ 
| psql -d db -c "COPY large_table FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV header"
```

```

I'm trying to reproduce this command in python and I am having a hard time finding the python equivalent for `sed`.

Using psycopg I can copy from STDIN using python:

```
with unzip('large_zip.zip', 'large_file.csv') as file:
    cr.copy_expert('''
        COPY large_table
        FROM STDIN
        DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
   ''', file)
```

The file is very big and is loaded directly form the zip file. I'm trying to avoid saving a local copy.

**What is the best way to process the file line by line and creating a file like object I can send as standard input to another command in python?**

Comment: Replacing an `_` with a `,` in python is trivial, just use `str.replace('_', ',')`, but I don't see anywhere where you have tried to do anything like that.

Comment: I'm working on a stream and i need to product a stream. To do what you suggest I would have to read the use a temporary file which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: To send lines to another process's stdin the use `subprocess` and run the program using a PIPE.

Comment: Or you could process standard input, and write to standard output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this recently and I can tell you there are a few ugly parts but it is definitely possible. I can't paste the code here verbatim because it's company internal.

The basic idea is this:

1. start the program which consumes data from `stdin` by spawning it like this:

   `command = subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`.
2. for each pipe (e.g. `command.stdin`) start a `threading.Thread` which writes to or reads from it. If you have multiple pipes you **need** multiple threads.
3. Wait for the exit of the program with `command.wait()` in the main thread.
4. Stop (join) all your threads so the program will not block. *You* have to make sure the threads exit by themselves by `return`ing from their `target` function.

### Simple Example (not tested!):

```
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys
import threading


lots_of_data = StringIO.StringIO()

import_to_db = subprocess.Popen(["import_to_db"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Make sure your input stream is at pos 0
lots_of_data.seek(0)

writer = threading.Thread(target=shutil.copyfileobj,
                          args=(lots_of_data, import_to_db.stdin))

writer.start()

return_code = import_to_db.wait()
if return_code:
    print "Error"
    sys.exit(1)

writer.join()
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. In my case `lots_of_data` can be an output stream from unzip? How would you pipe two commands, e.g, one for `sed` and one for `psql copy...`?

Comment: Either you pipe it via a shell pipe (see `shell=True` in the docs) or you spawn multiple threads, one each for the input/output of `sed` and one for the input of `psql` and then pass on the output of `sed` to the input thread of `psql`. I recommend the former.